# JMeter: PUT request is not accepting json body that has square braces

Tags: jmeter, request, put

When I am trying to pass this body in PUT body, it shows error.

```html
PUT data:
[{
    "myval":"9","value1":"10000"
}]
```

```html
{"status":9999,"message":"Something went wrong"}
```

Please help.

Comment: What error are you getting? Put a screenshot / copy-paste error.

Comment: something went wrong could not process the request.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we cannot help without seeing your:

1. API request contract (description, like [Swagger documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/))
2. Your test plan setup
3. The exact error you're getting
4. Server-side logs if they're available

The most common error when it comes to API testing is missing [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header, for requests with JSON you need to provide [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Metadata_and_schema) as the header value

So make sure to add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) to your Test Plan and supply the above information there

[image]

Comment: I have updated question, also, tried above solution but I see same error.